# which is best way to get the exact location for every 2 min even when device is in bag or pocket and without internet?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am developing an app in that i am given to options (start trip and end trip) where i have to track a person where he is travelling by getting location(lat,long),by clicking start and end options.when he start trip i have to save latlong  in local database after completing his trip and press stop trip i have to send total latlongs to server.by web application they can see root map by that latlongs.and it has to work when app closed(background) or killed also?

Comment: So it needs to work when the app isn't running?! How about if the device is powered off? Or the battery is depleted? Or the memory capacity is exhausted? Or the device is not in the possession of the person being tracked? Or isn't receiving GLONASS signals due to a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage)? What makes you think it is possible?

Comment: In application I am given start Trip option  if he or she start trip the trip will start i have to get locations when they press the start after finishing his trip if   he or she pressed the stop trip i have to stop to get locations. after finishing i have to send data and deleting previous data from my local data base.whether if device in pocket or bag or not using the app.no matter if the device turn off.

Comment: just i have to get location between start and end points.